ReactNative: Error while executing npm run android
I am working on a react native project and facing the some issues after running 'npm run android'.
Error message in terminal, package.json and build.gradle are listed as screenshots below.
Maybe, there is an issue with the dependencies but I am not sure what to do and overcome it.
I was expecting the app to run smoothly in the emulator.
Thanks for any given help
package.json
build.gradle
Error: PART 1
Error: PART 2

Please, would be nice to:

Inline the images in the question, if they are errors, try to copy the exception and its message in text, you can do this just dragging and dropping in the text editor.
Insert the code in the question, you can do this with triple backticks and the language name, e.g. kotlin .


Add this to your package.json:
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
},


Can you [edit] your answer to offer an explanation of what this is doing and why you think it will help?
